# How can Cohen's d < 1.96 ever be statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, cohens-d

I am having trouble understanding the statistical significance of [Cohen's d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen's_d).

My reasoning goes like this: 
To conclude that experimental group differs from control group significantly (p < 0.05), the experimental group's mean must be 1.96z below or above the control group's mean. In this case the Cohen's d will also be about 2, right? If Cohen's d is lower than 2, also the z difference between groups will be lower than that, which means the means from two groups won't be statistically different from each other anymore.

Please correct my flawed understanding.

Comment: Cohen's $d$ is determined using the standard deviation (typically of the available sample). Hypothesis testing is performed using the standard error $\frac{sd}{\sqrt{N}}$. The former assesses how big of a standardized difference you observed. The latter is used to determine the probability that you obtained a sample with the characteristics you did from a population of interest.

Answer (score 3):

A Cohen's $d$ is a standardized measure of difference. However, it is not weighted by the sample size. To go from a Cohen's $d$ to a $t$ statistics, the former must be mulitplied by $\sqrt{\tilde{n}/2}$ in which $\tilde{n}$ is the harmonic mean of the sample sizes. Conversely, the $t$ statistic is an effect size magnified by the sample size. The larger the sample, the bigger $t$ will end up. Hence, you could for example have a $t$ statistic of 1.96 (borderline significant) obtained from a sample of two groups, each containing two million participants. The resulting Cohen's $d$ is in that case a mere 0.00196! (yet, borderline significant!).

See [10.20982/tqmp.14.4.p242](https://doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.14.4.p242) for more.